# CPU Miner Compilation on Windows

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I want to compile this C++ project on windows using MinGW and MSYS

Project link: [CPU Miner](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer)

Source tarball: [CPU Miner.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpuminer/files/pooler-cpuminer-2.3.2.tar.gz)

In the README file, it's says that i've to:

```
* Make sure you have mstcpip.h in MinGW\include
* Make sure you have libcurl.m4 in MinGW\share\aclocal
* Make sure you have curl-config in MinGW\bin
```

No one of this files is in the right place in my computer, and i don't know where i can find theme.

Can you give me a detailed instruction to how compile it ? (i'm a newbie)

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right there in the [README](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/master/README) file you're quoting from...

```
Basic Windows build instructions, using MinGW:
  Install MinGW and the MSYS Developer Tool Kit (http://www.mingw.org/)
    * Make sure you have mstcpip.h in MinGW\include
  If using MinGW-w64, install pthreads-w64
  Install libcurl devel (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
    * Make sure you have libcurl.m4 in MinGW\share\aclocal
    * Make sure you have curl-config in MinGW\bin
  In the MSYS shell, run:
    ./autogen.sh # only needed if building from git repo
    LIBCURL="-lcurldll" ./configure CFLAGS="-O3"
    make
```

Doesn't really get more detailed than that.

Comment: like i said i don't have does files, from where i can get theme ?

Comment: If you read what I posted you'll find the urls for MinGW and libcurl in the text.

Comment: libcurl does not contains libcurl.m4 and curl-config + i don't know where to place it ? in the MinGW/include Directory ? or in the project's Directory ?

Comment: @Dark-Core You need to get the source package for libcurl (it's the zip-file at the top of the download page) then build it to generate the curl-config file. The .m4-file should already be there.